# Issues with async Method in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

Hi I have an issue with asp.net core.

I have a method in my controller..

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<SystemValidationViewModel> DoSomething(string model)
    {
        try
        {                
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This works fine locally, however when I deploy this to Azure it doesnt, in fact I get a 404 error. The only difference I can think of between the two is that Azure uses IIS7.5 while Im running under IISExpress.

Its worth point out that this is only happening for Async methods.

Any ideas as to what can be causing this issue?

Update:

Thanks, @andoni-zubizarreta, it seems like asp.net core methods don't need the async modifier as by default they are all async as we just had to get the result instead of the await...

Comment: Arent you required to `await` at least 1 call in a method marked with keyword `async`? Does this also occur if you remove the `async` keyword or add `await Task.Delay(1);`

Comment: @Igor In the method I actually have an await call, however its not required by any means.

Comment: @Igor if I remove async keyword it doesn't happen....

Comment: Is the 404 response immediate? If not maybe there is a time out due to a deadlock somewhere (example: calling Task<T>.Result in the call stack where async is being used in method signatures).

Comment: @Igor yes, it's immediate....

Comment: Then removing the async is the fix although I have seen plenty of examples from microsoft with async in the method signature so I am still perplexed as to why that is.

Comment: @Igor using asp.net core? are you sure? By default in asp.net core all method are async, no need for the modifier.

Comment: Positive. If you startup VS 2015 and MVC application -> Asp.Net 5 Templates -> Web Application it will create a new project with a bunch of "demo" code. Included are MVC controllers like the AccountController which have async methods like (verbatim copy/paste) `public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)`.

Comment: @Igor weird, although making those changes fixed my issue.... Its possible those samples no longer work with the latest asp.net releases... Interesting that locally this was not an issue.

Comment: So how do you know @Andoni Zubizarreta ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212970/asp-net-core-post-async-controller-method-not-found. Do you plan on answering his question and getting it marked as answer as well?

Comment: @Igor No, I don't plan on doing so because he found the answer. Not me...